# KafkaListener mulitple topics in yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to read from multiple topics, so i declared them in yaml file with comma separated but getting below error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [ topic-1 ,  topic-2,  topic-3,  topic-4,  topic-5,  topic-6,  topic-7] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

```
Spring:
  kafka:
    topics:
      tp: topic-1 ,  topic-2,  topic-3,  topic-4,  topic-5,  topic-6, topic-7
```

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.topics.tp}'.split(',')}",
        concurrency = "190",
        clientIdPrefix = "client1",
        groupId = "group1")
public void listenData(final ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> inputEvent) throws Exception {
    handleMessage(inputEvent);
}

if i declare all topics inside KafkaListener annotation its working fine.
```

Comment: `split(',')` returns a list rather than a CSV string

Comment: It returns an array not a `List<?>`; the problem looks like the leading/trailing spaces, especially `topic-1 ,`.

Comment: Remove the spaces or use `.split(' *, *')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces

```
tp: topic-1,topic-2,topic-3,topic-4,topic-5,topic-6,topic-7
```

Or use

```
.split(' *, *')
```